# Do we have $\int_{[0,1]^3} \min (x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz=6\int_0^1\int_0^y \int_0^z x \,dz\,dy\,dx?$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this nice question:
$\int_{[0,1]^3} \min (x,y,z)\,dx\,dy\,dz .$

I think it equals 
$6\int_0^1\int_0^z \int_0^y x \,dx\,dy\,dz .$
Then using my formula I got the result to be $\frac {1}{4} $
But when I used the hint below I got $\frac {17}{8} $
So what goes wrong?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

$$\min(x,y,z)=x\cdot (\boldsymbol 1_{x\leq y\leq z }+\boldsymbol 1_{x\leq z\leq z})+y\cdot (\boldsymbol 1_{y\leq x\leq z }+\boldsymbol 1_{y\leq z\leq x})+z\cdot (\boldsymbol 1_{z\leq x\leq y }+\boldsymbol 1_{z\leq y\leq x}).$$

It's now easy to compute the integral.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just want to see if my formula correct or not.

Comment: It  is  correct  formula